# Replace few symbols in all strings using QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, replace

I created the "Photos" column in the attribute table. Each line contains a unique path to a specific photo.
For example:

D:/.../IMG0031.JPG

D:/.../IMG0048.JPG

Now I need to replace the path for each photo from drive D to drive C.

C:/.../IMG0031.JPG

C:/.../IMG0048.JPG

At the same time, the right side in each line should not change!
What function should I use?

Answer (score 2):

In the field calculator, you can use the `replace` function.

You could just replace the drive letter or also change the folder structure.

```
replace(src,'D:/','C:/')
replace(src,'D:/a/b/c','C:/x/y')
```

If the renaming is slightly more complex, I suggest saving the renamed path on a new column as errors could lead to hard to recover (or just unrecoverable!) data.